# adding SPRING to an existing application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

This may be a silly question but I am having a hard time understanding what is the best practice to extend my application with a Spring-powered REST service.

I have a multi-threaded JAVA application and I would like to be able to create a separate Thread and do something like:

```
package payroll;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class PayrollApplication {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PayrollApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

After having my application and SPRING running, I would also like to be able to call SPRING CRUD API from my application and also notify my application when something happens in SPRING.

One option would be to wrap my class in a bean running in a CommandLineRunner so that my application can access the CRUD interface.

Is this a correct approach? Since I can't find documentation on this I have the feeling there is something fundamental that I am missing or not understanding.

Comment: Why not write a REST client in JAVA and invoke a REST endpoint to your Spring boot app. Write a service that Controller will call and that service will eventually do the CRUD and reply back to Controller which eventually will reply back to your REST Client.

Comment: I was hoping to reuse the code I wrote for the controllers and bundle my application but that is certainly a good option.

Comment: I found a solution, I will play with it for a couple of days and then I will post my finding hoping for some comments. The basic idea is to use the ConfigurableApplicationContext to get the beans that allow me to interact with my applications (either directly or through callback) and pass them to my application. I do wonder if this is an antipattern. Hopefully, once I am done someone more knowledgeable will let me know.

Comment: I am making significant progress in my research, the first that I figure out is that using getbean is discouraged. The correct way is to start a command-line runner and use the REST template. I will come back to this answer once I have time to test what I found.

Comment: The pattern I wanted to follow was not the correct one. The "right way" is that of communicating through rest. There are a couple of classes that SPRING brings to the table to help in that but I found it a little sad that the developers did not circumvent this limitation providing a solution on the line of what is possible to do by extracting the beans.